# network data in the form of hex convertion to ascii in python issue

Tags: python, hex, ascii

I'm trying to comprehend something, So I'm receiving data from raw network data in the form of HEX, in this particular example a MAC address, now I'm using the **Unhexlify() / Hexilfy()** functions from the **Binascii** library in Python 2.7, and for example, I'm recieving for example the following MAC address in the form of hex

**"\xa5\xbb%\x8f\xa0\xda"**

it's a six octet long mac address and I absolutely have no clue what's going on....

if I use the function

```
binascii.hexlify('\xa5\xbb%\x8f\xa0\xda')
```

it returns

```
a5bb258fa0da
```

which is indeed the correct MAC address I'm expecting to receive but this really really doesn't make sense.... 
**"\xa5\xbb%\x8f\xa0\xda"**, this isn't correct form of HEX, it contains a **%**, and somehow the **binascii.hexlify()** function manages to translate it to the correct mac address...

I'm honestly failing to understand this, I'm guessing it has something to do with translating from hex to ascii and not hex to dec, but I'm failing to understand how the **unhexlify() / hexlify()** functions work, and how come I'm receiving data in a form of hex and it contains a **%** in it, and yet my hex to ascii function manages to handle it...
what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andrey is right, if characters are not preceded by the `\x` the standard ASCII table is used:

[image]

```
>>> print binascii.hexlify('012')
'303132'
```

Comment: Not the *whole* ASCII table, just the parts 0x20 to 0x7e.

Comment: I didn't understand why this binascii.hexlify('0') returns 30... could you explain to me again?

Comment: @user3687265 the character `'0'` is ASCII symbol number 48 in the table, 48 in base 16 is 30.

Answer (score 1):

`"\xa5\xbb%\x8f\xa0\xda"` - it is a sequence of characters that are defined by their hex code. One character is `"\xa5"`, it is single character, not 4. For example `print '\x61'` will produce just `a`.

About % sign, it is printable character that is why it printed as is in the string. It has hex code of `0x25` which is actually used. you can write it as `\x25`: `"\xa5\xbb\x25\x8f\xa0\xda"`
More [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals).

Comment: This does not explain the `%` after the second character `\xbb`

Comment: @user3687265 it is just a character that happen to have code `25`. Nothing more nothing less.